# Outlook email list changed look

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365

My Outlook suddenly changed the look of how it displays the list of e-mails in the main pane.

I am not sure if I pressed some button by mistake, but I would like to revert to the current default interface.

I have:

- tried playing with the 'View' Settings, but am unable to solve the issue.
- extensively searched the internet for solutions but to no avail.
- uninstalled and then reinstalled, but that did not solve the problem.

I'm using an Education version of Office 365.

This is how my Outlook looks like (sorry for the heavy highlighting):
[image: My Outlook View]

And this is how my Outlook is suppose to look:
[image: Default Outlook View]

Note that, in the desired (default) view:

- On the first line, the names of the sender are large.
- The second line is the subject.
- The last line is a one line preview of the e-mail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To restore Outlook to its default view settings:

- Close Outlook.
- Open the Run dialog box by pressing the Win + R key.
- Type `outlook /cleanviews` and click OK.

Outlook will open and reset all views to default.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had found a similar solution online, but that did not work. But, yours does. I think the previous one I tried was 'outlook.exe / cleanviews'

Answer (score 0):

The view you are looking for is called "Compact"

This is how you restore the default view in Outlook.

*Using simplified ribbon:*

- Select "**View**" from the menu.
- Then **click on** "**Change View**" and **choose** "**Compact**" from the drop down.

*Using classic ribbon:*

- Select "**View**" from the menu.
- Then **click on** "**Reset View**".

Another method is to reset the view running a command in Windows:

- **Open** the **Run dialog box** (by pressing the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> keys).
- **Type** "**outlook.exe /cleanviews**" and **press Enter**.